# Search sql database using select dropdown?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, search, select

I have managed get the search function to work but it is very chunky :(

Code:

```
If dropdown_sV.Value = "N" Then
        If WhereParts > 0 Then
            WhereClause = WhereClause & " AND"
        End If
        WhereClause = WhereClause & " [sV] = 'N'"
        WhereParts = WhereParts + 1
    End If

    If dropdown_sV.Value = "G" Then
        If WhereParts > 0 Then
            WhereClause = WhereClause & " AND"
        End If
        WhereClause = WhereClause & " [sV] = 'G'"
        WhereParts = WhereParts + 1
    End If
```

Can I make this code more efficient because I have lots of select dropdowns with the following options: N, G, O, A, R, U

It would be a nightmare to maintain my application.

Comment: Please disregard my previous version of this question - I have managed to solve it but am now looking for a more efficient method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
If dropdown_sV.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
    If WhereClause.Length > 0 Then
        WhereClause = WhereClause & " AND"
    End If
    WhereClause = WhereClause & " [sV] = " & dropdown_sV.Value
End If
```

but you really should consider parameterizing your query (like so):

```
If dropdown_sV.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
    If WhereClause.Length > 0 Then
        WhereClause = WhereClause & " AND"
    End If
    WhereClause = WhereClause & " [sV] = @sV"
End If
```

After the `WHERE` clause is built, you merely have to associate the parameters with the value:

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(queryString, connectionString)
cmd.Parameters.Add("sV", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = dropdown_sV.Value
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use only at once the code i.e. 
write for every time for dropdown selection. you can reduce the code as:

```
If WhereParts > 0 Then
  WhereClause = WhereClause & " AND"
  End If
  string value=dropdown_sV.Value;
  WhereClause = WhereClause & " [sV] = '"+dropdown_sV.Value+"'"
  WhereParts = WhereParts + 1
```